Refining a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for a base $X$ of a covering map $q:E \to X$ to an evenly covered basis $\mathcal{B}'$.
Is it true that for any basis $\mathcal{B}$ of base $X$ of a covering map $q:E \to X$, we can discard the non-evenly covered basis elements in $\mathcal{B}$ and still get a basis $\mathcal{B}' \subseteq \mathcal{B}$? The answer seems to be yes, but I can't figure out how to prove it.
It is the case that an open subset of an evenly covered neighborhood is evenly covered, and we know that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis if and only if for each neighborhood $U \subseteq X$ and each $x \in U$ there is some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subseteq U$. Taking an evenly covered neighborhood $U_x$ for each $x \in X$, we see that we can find an evenly covered basis element $B_x$ for each $x \in X$. Assembling all such $B_x$ gives us a set $\mathcal{B}' := \{B_x \;|\; x \in X\}$  such that $\bigcup\limits_{x \in X} B_x = X$. But I am having trouble showing that we can get any open set $V \subseteq X$ by taking union of elements $B_x \in \mathcal{B}'$. I don't see why this should hold. What am I missing/doing wrong?

Ok, I discussed this with GPT1o, and I think I see what to do; we can apply prop. 2.44 in "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" by J. Lee, and it follows (AFAICT) quite directly that both requirements there are satisfied, hence $\mathcal{B}'$ as defined in the post is a basis for a topology on $X$.
